# Words having two converse meanings

Tags: vocabulary, ambiguity

Many words have several meanings and some even have two converse meanings. Two examples of such words are *amateur* and *literally* as illustrated by the following:

- She is an art amateur.
- This is amateur work.

and

- Don't take my remarks literally.
- He literally lost his mind for a few seconds.

Which other words from the common vocabulary do display this feature? (Less common examples are also welcome!) Does this feature have a name?

Answer (score 2):

*Literally* seems to have simply been overused as a *hyperbole*. 
When a hyperbole, a style figure that can be very powerful, is used too often, it loses its impact. This is a common phenomenon.
I remember when it was common to say you were giving a 100% (of your effort) to a cause. That was already a hyperbole, but once everybody seemed to be giving their 100%, people started giving their 110%, and by now some people are *going for it, 200%*!

As the hyperbole gets overused, it loses its effect and its meaning.
In the case of *literally*, it has been overused so much that people consciously interpret it as “ok, what follows is meant to be interpreted *figuratively*”.

As for [*amateur*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=amateur&searchmode=none), I don't see any similar issue.

In describing someone as an art amateur, you stay close to the original meaning of *lover* or *enthusiast*. In this case, the opposite of *amateur* is one who is simply not interested.

In describing something as *amateur work*, you contrast it with *professional work*. In this case, the opposite is *professional*.

For those two meanings of *amateur* to be seen as antonyms, you should somehow be able to relate *disinterested* with *professional*, but I fail to see that link.

So, *amateur* has different meanings, but I fail to see how they are converse.

Comment: Sometimes we call someone an amateur if he has some knowledge on a topic, sometimes we call someone an amateur if he has very little knowledge on a topic.

Answer (score 0):

This question will probably be closed as a "list type question" but I'll add my favourite:

Egregious:

> 1 Outstandingly bad; shocking:

> 2 *archaic* Remarkably good.

Comment: Except, as the *archaic* marker indicates, no one uses *egregious* to mean *good* any more.

Comment: Agreed but I just love how polarized the two meanings are.